# No such file or directory error after SSH with appleboy/ssh-action

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions, vps

I have no idea why my script keeps on giving error:

```yaml
name: Node.js Workflow CI/CD

# Trigger the workflow on push and
# pull request events on the master branch
on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

# Authenticate to the the server via ssh
# and run our deployment script
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Deploy to Server
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}
          script: "cd root@XXXX:/project && ./.scripts/deploy.sh"
```

and the error is:

```
======CMD======
cd ***@***:/project && ./.scripts/deploy.sh
======END======
err: bash: line 1: cd: ***@***:/project: No such file or directory
2024/02/07 15:39:*** Process exited with status 1
```

For reference, my `project` directory is:

[image: project]

I would really appreciate if someone can please help, thank you so much!

Comment: You're checking out the code on the GHA hosted runner, not on your remote machine. Is your script `.scripts/deploy.sh` supposed to run on the remote machine or from the GHA hosted run? Before `cd project`, that `cd root@XXXX:/project` doesn't look correct as you're already there after SSH, you need to make sure that your project is already cloned there. Depending on your use case, you can make a clone there first and then in your workflow only pull the latest code when needed.

Comment: `cd root@XXXX:/project` makes no sense.